# Restricting the type of values for custom dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a custom dictionary class `NewDict` with its own set of methods and what not.  I would like to make another custom dictionary class `CustomDictionary`, such that the value of every key in this custom dictionary is of the class `NewDict`.

Right now I have:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from NewDict import NewDict

class CustomDictionary(OrderedDict):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomDictionary, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

so what do I have to add so that this class knows that every value in it is of `NewDict`?

```
class NewDict(dict):
  _keys = ['my_key_1', 'my_key_2', ...]
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    for key in self._keys:
      if key in kwargs:
        self[key] = kwargs[key]
      else:
        self[key]  = None
  <various methods>
```

Comment: Can you show NewDict module?

Comment: You ought to implement one on the following abstract class: `collections.MutableMapping` or `collections.Mapping`.

Comment: Please define what the class knowing that every value in it is of type `NewDict` means. (I assume by "the class" you mean `CustomDictionary`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in my comment, you can implements [collections.MutableMapping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.MutableMapping).

Here is an exemple using an internal dictionary. You can use a classic `dict` or any other dictionary-like classes.

```
class NewDict(dict):
    pass


import collections


class CustomDictionary(collections.MutableMapping):
    """ A dictionary which contains only ``NewDict`` values. """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._data = dict()  # or collections.OrderedDict, etc.
        self.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self._data.__iter__()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if not isinstance(value, NewDict):
            raise TypeError(repr(type(value)))
        self._data.__setitem__(key, value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self._data.__delitem__(key)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._data.__getitem__(key)

    def __len__(self):
        return self._data.__len__()
```

Like presented by Or Duan, you can make type checking. I prefer using `isinstance` for that, to allow instances of a subclasses of `NewDict`.

- Pros: `collections.MutableMapping` implements all classic `dict` methods, like `get`, `update`, `setdefault` and so on.
- Cons: this implementation use Abstract Base Classes which insert some magic methods in your class. But they are documented.

Then, you can use this dictionary like any other dictionary:

```
custom_dict = CustomDictionary()
custom_dict["key1"] = NewDict()
custom_dict["key1"]["my_key_1"] = 3.14

inner_dict = custom_dict["key2"] = NewDict()
inner_dict["my_key_1"] = 2
inner_dict["my_key_2"] = 4
```

If you add the following methods, you can print the values:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self._data.__str__()

    __repr__ = __str__
```

With the Dictionary above:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(custom_dict)
```

You get:

```
{'key2': {'my_key_2': 4, 'my_key_1': 2}, 'key1': {'my_key_1': 3.14}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A few things. 1.) I want it to be an ordered dictionary, does using mutable mapping maintain that? 2.) how would I set it so self is the dictionary not self.data? 3.) This doesn't really seem to restrict the value, it only prevents it from being assigned something else.... lastly and unimportant, how could I updated autocomplete to know to use methods from the set value?

Comment: @SumNeuron: Do you want insertion order or key order ? For the first one, you can use: `self._data = collections.OrderedDict()`.

Comment: key most likely, as are keys not generated with insertion? Does self._data allow me to call self["key"] or will I still have to type self._data["key"]

Comment: @SumNeuron: For question 2) and 3), I don't really understand. What is your use case? Could you edit with a expected usage?

Comment: 2.) if I am understanding correctly you are setting an instance of a dictionary to self.data. I want self to be the dictionary, not self to have an attribute which is a dictionary.  for 3.) since this class inherits from mutable mapping or ordered dictionary, the values dont have any methods. but I may want to call an instance of my custom dictionary, get its value, and invoke a method on the value

Comment: You can use it like any other dictionary. I edited to show a classic usage. Try this class, I'll be surprised ;-)

Comment: That is well and good, but the class definition I have posted in my question has all those capabilities as well. The crux of the question is overwriting what dictionary accepts as values and making (both) the class (and the IDE if possible) understand that every value in the dictionary will be of class `NewDict`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by overriding the [`__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.setitem) method. This is python3 example:

```
class CustomDictionary(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if type(value) != NewDict:
              raise TypeError("Can't do that :(")
```

Please note that this has some overhead for each insert.

Comment: Raising `TypeError` will be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes except autocomplete within this new class won't show `NewDict` class methods when accessing values....

Comment: @SumNeuron I would never make code changes(that hurt performance and readability) just to make IDE autocomplete a bit better. If that what you try to achieve include it in the question.

Comment: Well it isn't just about autocomplete... but since part of this Custom Dictionary class is containing only this specific type of value it seems appropriate